# $\nabla F(x) = x\vec{1}^t \nabla f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

Determine a scalar function $F$ such that $$\nabla F(x) = x\vec{1}^t\, \nabla f(x),$$
where $\vec{1}=(1,\dots,1)$ and $f$ is a given scalar function.

This looks almost trivial, but I'm stuck.

Comment: What is $f$ in the RHS?

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. Added.